# Prolog, a list of the most common list items

Tags: prolog

Write a predicate that forms a list of the most common
list items. The list is entered from the keyboard while the predicate is running.
Do not use the built-in maximum search and sort predicates!
For example: [0,3,5,7,1,5,3,0,3,3,5,7,0,5,0] -> [0,3,5].

I have such a code, but I do not understand what the function "cou" does in it, and what is the comparison between K and MX.

```
f :-
        read(List),bubble_sort(List, SList) , cou(SList, _, ResList), write(ResList).

    bubble_sort(InputList, SortList):- 
        swap(InputList, List) , !,  bubble_sort(List, SortList).
    bubble_sort(SortList, SortList).

    swap([X,Y|List], [Y,X|List]):- X > Y.
    swap([Z|List], [Z|List1]):- swap(List, List1).

    cou([], 0, []).
    cou([H|T], K, [H]) :-
        foo([H|T], H, K, List), cou(List, MX, _), K > MX, !.
    cou([H|T], MX, List1) :-
        foo([H|T], H, K, List), cou(List, MX, List1), K < MX, !.
    cou([H|T], MX, [H|List1]) :-
        foo([H|T], H, K, List), cou(List, MX, List1), K =:= MX.

    foo([], _, 0, []) :- !.
    foo([H|T], X, 0, [H|T]) :- H \== X, !.
    foo([H|T], X, K, T1) :-  H =:= X,  foo(T, X, K1, T1), K is K1 + 1.
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How the function works "cou"